# Is there an interface for network interface error data

Tags: c++, linux, networking, concurrency, network-programming

I'm trying to find an interface to track error linux network data such as the errors/dropped/overruns/frame errors displayed with ifconfig or ethtool.
I've been grepping through /usr/include attempting to find something with no luck.

I realize this may just be a boolean flag as opposed to a counter which will be fine since I'm just trying to track overruns over time.

Does a system call, or global variable exist for this information?

### UPDATE

As suggested I took a look at the output of strace and as suggested and suspected, most of the information does seem to come by way of the ioctl library, however error data seems to come from a flat /proc file which I was not aware of "/proc/net/dev"

This generates a couple of questions:

1. If the only information I need is in that file, would I need to even bother with sockets?
2. How fast can I query this information without causing detriment to the system?  I want to have time stamps associated with overflows, and I was hoping to monitor at 5s intervals but ramp up to 0.5s or less when the value begins to increment.
3. I tried to capture the buffer using read()/write()/mmap() and the other commands mentioned in strace, and having some difficulty doing so.  If I were to just use fstream instead would this be any more/less likely to cause blocking/threading issues?

   ```
   dmf86@tux5:/$ strace ifconfig eth0
   ```

   execve("/sbin/ifconfig", ["ifconfig", "eth0"], 0x7ffc92588278 /* 24 vars */) = 0
   brk(NULL)                               = 0x565327409000
   access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
   fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=227061, ...}) = 0
   mmap(NULL, 227061, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2f042af000
   close(3)                                = 0
   access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
   read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260\34\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
   fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2030544, ...}) = 0
   mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2f042ad000
   mmap(NULL, 4131552, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2f03ccf000
   mprotect(0x7f2f03eb6000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
   mmap(0x7f2f040b6000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e7000) = 0x7f2f040b6000
   mmap(0x7f2f040bc000, 15072, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f2f040bc000
   close(3)                                = 0
   arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f2f042ae540) = 0
   mprotect(0x7f2f040b6000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
   mprotect(0x565326999000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
   mprotect(0x7f2f042e7000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
   munmap(0x7f2f042af000, 227061)          = 0
   brk(NULL)                               = 0x565327409000
   brk(0x56532742a000)                     = 0x56532742a000
   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
   fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3004464, ...}) = 0
   mmap(NULL, 3004464, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2f039f1000
   close(3)                                = 0
   uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="tux5", ...}) = 0
   access("/proc/net", R_OK)               = 0
   access("/proc/net/unix", R_OK)          = 0
   socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)          = 3
   socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
   access("/proc/net/if_inet6", R_OK)      = 0
   socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 5
   access("/proc/net/ax25", R_OK)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   access("/proc/net/nr", R_OK)            = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   access("/proc/net/rose", R_OK)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   access("/proc/net/ipx", R_OK)           = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   access("/proc/net/appletalk", R_OK)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   access("/proc/sys/net/econet", R_OK)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   access("/proc/sys/net/ash", R_OK)       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   access("/proc/net/x25", R_OK)           = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/net/dev", O_RDONLY) = 6
   fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
   read(6, "Inter-|   Receive               "..., 1024) = 470
   read(6, "", 1024)                       = 0
   close(6)                                = 0
   ioctl(5, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="eth0"}) = -1 ENODEV (No such device)
   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
   fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2995, ...}) = 0
   read(6, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2995
   read(6, "", 4096)                       = 0
   close(6)                                = 0
   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/net-tools.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   write(2, "eth0: error fetching interface i"..., 61eth0: error fetching interface information: Device not found
   ) = 61
   close(5)                                = 0
   exit_group(1)                           = ?
   +++ exited with 1 +++

Comment: Note to close-voters: I don't think this is a request for library. It's more a "What Linux system call do I use to get network interface statistics?"

Comment: Maybe take a look at [`net-tools/ifconfig.c`](https://www.google.com/search?q=ifconfig+filetype%3Ac&oq=ifconfig+filetype%3Ac) source code (and [`statistics.c`](https://github.com/giftnuss/net-tools/blob/master/statistics.c)). It looks like `ioctl` is used.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my research above.